# WebApi json to csv client download

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, export-to-csv

I need my application to hit the database, build up a list of my objects, format as csv string then return back to client javascript for client to download as a csv file.

Can this be done with MVC4 webapi controllers? Client is using IE8 so the method creating my own CsvFormatter class inheriting the MediaTypeFormatter then building up string and letting user save client side with the following is not possible as IE8 doesn't support the Download attribute.......

Any help appreciated.